# Locked Samsung A51

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, data-recovery, pattern-lock

My Samsung A51 has been locked since 28th of December 2023. My AHDH son changed my pattern and can’t remember the pattern. I have tried different patterns every day and can’t seem to unlock the phone, now I can only try a new pattern every 24 hours. I have watched all your videos and can't unlock my phone,

I have entered the phone into save mode and after restarting the phone it’s not on flight mode and can’t get flight mode off, I do not want to lose my photos on my phone. Would you be able to please assist me.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but by rebooting you have destroyed the last theoretical chance to get access to your files without knowing the pattern (under the assumption that there is a exploit to bypass the lock screen on your phone which is not always true). User data on Android is encrypted by a key that requires the PIN (that is derived from the lock pattern). So now you have to enter the correct pattern to make Android getting the encryption key to access the files. No pattern means no key means no files.

Comment: How can I get access to the photos without getting into the phone, I still have my screen saver photo the same

Comment: Try giving another phone to your son and ask him to set new pattern. Unknowingly, he might put the same pattern again that can unlock your device. It may require several attempts. Brute forcing it is the only way. Most people usually think of patterns that are common.